Change Camera Properties (fps, exposure, white balance) in Android Camera App
I'd like to develop a camera app for video capturing in Android Studio using Kotlin language where I can manually change the camera properties within the app to alter frame rate, exposure and white balance.
I have experience creating layouts and UI in Android Studio but have very little experience with the Kotlin language, so I'd very much appreciate any tips on how go on with this task.
I am currently working with a sample app from the CameraX API (CameraXVideo: https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXVideo) which is already able to capture videos, save them internally, change camera resolution, enable/disable audio and flip the camera.
I'd like to add the functionality of accessing system information on the camera parameters and then be able to change them. I'm thinking of a button to switch between 30 and 60 fps and sliders to adjust white balance and exposure.
